# Display as tree terms of taxonomy and custom posts for each term of taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have cpt "Document" and Taxonomy Document categories with terms "AML" and "Corporate Governance". For each term there are children "EU", "National Law", etc..

I want to display as Tree All Terms, subterms and assigned posts.

My tree with Terms/subterms:

[image]

I want to add assigned posts to each term as leafs to the tree. My code is the following:

```php
function rgt_generate_taxonomy_tree_lampros($taxonomy) {
    $taxonomies = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false
    ));
    $grouped = array();
    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $par = $taxonomy->parent;
        if ( !isset($grouped[$par]) ) $grouped[$par] = array();
        array_push($grouped[$par], $taxonomy);
    }
    $tree = array();
    rgt_fill_taxonomy_tree_lampros(0, $tree, $grouped);
    
    return $tree;
}

function rgt_fill_taxonomy_tree_lampros($parent_id, &$parent, $data) {
    if ( !isset($data[$parent_id]) || count($data[$parent_id]) == 0 ) return;
    $parent['children'] = array();
    foreach ( $data[$parent_id] as $item ) {
        $newitem = array(
            'name' => $item->name,
            'id' => $item->slug
        );
        rgt_fill_taxonomy_tree_lampros($item->term_id, $newitem, $data);
        array_push( $parent['children'], $newitem );
    }
    $parent['children'] = rgt_array_sort($parent['children'], 'name');
}
```

Comment: can you explain better what the missing parts are that you're unsure of? It looks like you've already figured out fetching the terms which is the hardest part, I'm not sure what it is that you need help with to finish it?

Comment: I need to display the posts for each term. For example AML/EU/post1, AML/EU/post2 etc...